# How to convert action view to pdf using TCPDF in zend Framework 2.2

Tags: pdf, zend-framework2, tcpdf

I want to export a view content from a controller action into pdf.I am not able to get content of loadAction. 
There are two action :

```
public function loadAction(){
    //some data
}

public function generatepdfAction(){
    $pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    $htmlcontent = $view->setTemplate('caremodule/carecontroller/load');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output("pdftest.pdf", 'D');
}
```

Comment: What/how is the data returned from the `loadAction` method?

Comment: why don't create a protected funciton generatedpdf() and call from loadAction(),  calling one action from anther is not a good idea